# Phonegap Android App not working on Android KitKat

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I have created a phonegap app and it works fine on Android 4.3 and lower. On 4.4 it throws and error on clicking any link:

> net:: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///loginPage)

Error seen in the backend is :

> ```
> > 12-18 17:04:36.214: V/info(17666): Open sqlite db:
> > /data/data/com.sample.sampleapp/databases/sample_db.db 12-18
> > 17:04:36.214: E/SQLiteLog(17666): (14) cannot open file at line 30191
> > of [00bb9c9ce4] 12-18 17:04:36.214: E/SQLiteLog(17666): (14)
> > os_unix.c:30191: (2)
> > open(/data/data/com.sample.sampleapp/databases/sample_db.db) - 
> > 12-18 17:04:36.214: D/CordovaLog(17666):
> > file:///android_asset/www/js/phonegap_interface.js: Line 55 : Going to
> > initialize database if required 12-18 17:04:36.214: I/chromium(17666):
> > [INFO:CONSOLE(55)] "Going to initialize database if required", source:
> > file:///android_asset/www/js/phonegap_interface.js (55) 12-18
> > 17:04:36.214: D/CordovaLog(17666):
> > file:///android_asset/www/js/phonegap_interface.js: Line 66 : Going to
> > open database sample_db 12-18 17:04:36.214: I/chromium(17666):
> > [INFO:CONSOLE(66)] "Going to open database sample_db", source:
> > file:///android_asset/www/js/phonegap_interface.js (66) 12-18
> > 17:04:36.214: D/CordovaLog(17666):
> > file:///android_asset/www/js/SQLitePlugin.js: Line 8 : SQLitePlugin
> > openargs: {"name":"sample_db"} 12-18 17:04:36.214: I/chromium(17666):
> > [INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "SQLitePlugin openargs: {"name":"sample_db"}",
> > source: file:///android_asset/www/js/SQLitePlugin.js (8) 12-18
> > 17:04:36.214: E/SQLiteDatabase(17666): Failed to open database
> > '/data/data/com.sample.sampleapp/databases/sample_db.db'. 12-18
> > 17:04:36.214: E/SQLiteDatabase(17666):
> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error
> > (code 14): Could not open database
> ```

Comment: how are you loading webview?

Comment: How you use the particular "path/filename"?

Comment: "file:///android_asset/www/" + filename

Do note that it works as expected in Android 4.3 and lower

Comment: make the name of the page as index.html and now it should work in every platform

Comment: I can't name all my files index.html :/

Comment: You no need to. But make the first page as index.html and you should load the webview as index.html

Comment: The first one is and that loads as expected, on clicking any of the links in that page I get the error I have mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be an issue with one of the plugins I was using Cordova-SQLitePlugin.
Basically the database directory has to be created if it doesn't exist. It has been fixed now.

[Create db directory if it doesn't exist](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin/commit/808d11c116d041370f3134c44481e33716dec7aa)